# How to limit lookups in many-to-many relationship based on related record attributes?

Tags: lightning-experience, record-type, lookup-filter, junction-object

I have created a many-to-many relation between `Contact` and `Skill`, a custom object that represents a contact's skills. A contact can be one of two different record types, `Type A` and `Type B`.

I want to segment skills in the `Skill` object based on which are relevant to the contact type (`A` or `B`), so that when new `Contact Skill` records are created from the `Contact`, only those skills related to the type of contact  (`A` or `B`) are available for selection.

I am currently using Record Type on `Skill` to determine if the skill is of `Type A` or `Type B`.

The users are still using Classic UI, but I want this solution to work in LEX as well.

Are there any patterns or common solutions to this problem? I want to do this without hard-coding record type IDs in custom buttons if possible, and would like the solution to work in both Classic UI as we as Lightning Experience.

Comment: What would be the criteria for selecting specific skill to a contact? Eg. Do you have a picklist on Skill which determines whether it should be associated with a particular type of Contact? If so, I'm thinking you should be able to do it with a lookup filter?

Comment: I agree that lookup filter will be involved, but what will it filter on? Question has been updated with answer to your quesiton, @Ranga.

Comment: I see what you mean, we can't add a lookup filter as there is a limitation when comparing Parent record type value with Child record type value. We should be able to add a validation rule but user experience will not be great. The other solution I could think of is a custom lightning component which can be invoked as a quick action.